# URL rewrite через IIS ошибка 413 full head

Tags: iis, rewrite

Коллеги, добрый день!
Цель: Дать доступ из мира к внутреннему сайту через IIS на пограничном сервере с помощью SSL.
Rewrite правила были настроены, но IIS не хочет отрабатывать URL запросы, которые имеют очень большое количество символов. Пример на скриншоте. Через средства разработчика просматривается ошибка 413 Full head. Как поправить данную ошибку в конфигах IIS?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как у вас настроен SSL?

Comment: @RomanC Развернута ферма для сервера, в биндингах сайта прикреплен SSL сертификат и настроено правило ARR в настройках основного сайта IIS.

Comment: Какое еще правило?

Comment: @RomanC Скриншот прилагается по ссылке, могу конфиг кинуть еще. !(https://c.radikal.ru/c38/1804/de/68a6664ef580.jpg)